# Trim leading zeroes from second component of a string

Tags: c#, strings, .net

I have a collection of strings as follows:

> 44.01
>   44.02
>   44.03
>   44.04
>   44.12
>   46.05
>   46

... and so on.

I want to remove leading zeros from the component of the string *after* the full stop.

As you can see from above, not all strings have a sub-component and not all sub-components will have leading zeros.

Is there a more elegant way of doing that from my attempt?

```
    List<string> codesWithSubCodes = new List<string>
    {
        "44.01", "44.02", "44.03", "44.04", "44.05", "44.06", "44.07", "44.08"
    };

    var codes = new List<string>();
    foreach (var code in codesWithSubCodes)
    {
        if (code.Contains('.'))
        {
            var prefix = code.Split('.')[0];
            var subCode = code.Split('.')[1].TrimStart('0');
            codes.Add(prefix + '.' + subCode);
        }
        else
        {
            codes.Add(code);
        }
    }

    foreach (var code in codes)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(code);
    }
```

Comment: Are you trying to turn them into numbers?

Comment: No, they will always remain as strings.

Comment: Is there ever more than 1 `0`? (`46.002`)

Comment: No, the second component of each string (if there is a 2nd component) will always have 2 characters.

Comment: In that case, I just recommended two methods that could help you out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The biggest thing I can see, which may or may not be an issue, is the manner in which you process the strings.

> ```
>     if (code.Contains('.'))
>     {
>         var prefix = code.Split('.')[0];
>         var subCode = code.Split('.')[1].TrimStart('0');
>         codes.Add(prefix + '.' + subCode);
>     }
>     else
>     {
>         codes.Add(code);
>     }
> ```

This **could** be rewritten as:

```
var codeSections = code.Split('.');
var code = codeSections[0];

if (codeSections.Length == 2)
    code += "." + codeSections[1].TrimStart('0');

codes.Add(code);
```

This saves you LoC, and probably makes it faster. (You could also possible make this a `StringBuilder` as well.) And in my opinion, this is more readable/concise/descriptive.

Another alternative:

```
code = code.Replace(".0", ".");
```

Both should have the same effect on the cases you provided.

However, if, for whatever reason, one of the cases ends up as `46.00`, then the second method will only make it `46.0`. Choose that method with great caution.

As the OP pointed out in an edit that should have been a comment, this code can all be done as LINQ:

```
var codes = codesWithSubCodes.ConvertAll(code => code.Replace(".0", "."));
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to remove *any* number of leading zeros from the second component of your string then you can do:

```
var query = codesWithSubCodes.Select(r=> new
            {
                SplitResult = r.Split('.'),
                OriginalValue = r
            })
            .Select(r=> 
            r.SplitResult.Length == 2 ? 
            r.SplitResult.First() + "." + r.SplitResult.Last().TrimStart('0')
            : r.OriginalValue
            );
```

This is how this query works:

- First `Split` the string on delimiter and store it temporarily so that you don't have to do `Split` multiple times
- Later it checks if the result of `Split` is a 2 element array then return concatenation of first element , delimiter and last element with removing all the `0`s from the beginning.
- If the `Split` results in length not being `2`, then return the original element.

With respect to your code, you can improve following thing:

- Do not check for delimiter `Contains`, instead `Split` the string and check length. That way you only `Split` the element *once*.

So the iteration part could look like:

```
foreach (var code in codesWithSubCodes)
{
    string[] SplitResult = code.Split('.');
    if (SplitResult.Length == 2)
    {
        var prefix = SplitResult[0];
        var subCode = SplitResult[1].TrimStart('0');
        codes.Add(prefix + '.' + subCode);
    }
    else
    {
        codes.Add(code);
    }
}
```

If you are always going to have a single zero after the `.` then you can use this simple LINQ query:

```
var codes = codesWithSubCodes.Select(r => r.Replace(".0", ".")).ToList();
```

Comment: This is a very intriguing answer, I never thought to use LINQ like that for this one.